# Moving from classification to counting in Tensorflow with MNIST style structure

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am attempting to use the MNIST convolution neural network training structure, but instead of doing classification I want to do counting, meaning my output should be a scalar instead of a softmax. I'm having trouble moving from the `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy` to `mean_squared_error` as my loss function. The specific error I am getting is:

> ValueError: Shapes (100, 1) and (100,) are incompatible

but I also assume that my `predictions` function is set up incorrectly as well, due to it using argmax and softmax. I've pasted in all of the code below, but I think the issue is in the loss function and the predictions function.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)


def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode):
  """Model function for CNN."""
  # Input Layer
  # Reshape X to 4-D tensor: [batch_size, width, height, channels]
  # Rack images are 116x116 pixels, and have one color channel
  input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"], [-1, 116, 116, 1])

  # Convolutional Layer #1
  # Computes 32 features using a 5x5 filter with ReLU activation.
  # Padding is added to preserve width and height.
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 116, 116, 1]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 116, 116, 32]
  conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=input_layer,
      filters=32,
      kernel_size=[5, 5],
      padding="same",
      activation=tf.nn.relu)

  # Pooling Layer #1
  # First max pooling layer with a 2x2 filter and stride of 2
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 116, 116, 32]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 58, 58, 32]
  pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

  # Convolutional Layer #2
  # Computes 64 features using a 5x5 filter.
  # Padding is added to preserve width and height.
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 58, 58, 32]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 58, 58, 64]
  conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=pool1,
      filters=64,
      kernel_size=[5, 5],
      padding="same",
      activation=tf.nn.relu)

  # Pooling Layer #2
  # Second max pooling layer with a 2x2 filter and stride of 2
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 58, 58, 64]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 29, 29, 64]
  pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

  # Flatten tensor into a batch of vectors
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 29, 29, 256]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 29 * 29 * 256]
  pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 29 * 29 * 64])

  # Dense Layer
  # Densely connected layer with 1024 neurons
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 29 * 29 * 256]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 1024]
  dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)

  # Add dropout operation; 0.6 probability that element will be kept
  dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
      inputs=dense, rate=0.4, training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

  # Logits layer
  # Input Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 1024]
  # Output Tensor Shape: [batch_size, 5]
  logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=1)

  predictions = {
      # Generate predictions (for PREDICT and EVAL mode)
      "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
      # Add `softmax_tensor` to the graph. It is used for PREDICT and by the
      # `logging_hook`.
      "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
  }
  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)

  # Calculate Loss (for both TRAIN and EVAL modes)
  loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=labels, predictions=logits)

  # Configure the Training Op (for TRAIN mode)
  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

  # Add evaluation metrics (for EVAL mode)
  eval_metric_ops = {
      "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(
          labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"])}
  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
      mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)


def main(unused_argv):
  # Load training and eval data
  train_data = np.load('Train_data.npy').astype(dtype=np.float32)  # Returns np.array
  train_labels = np.load('Train_labels.npy').astype(dtype=np.int32) 
  eval_data = np.load('Eval_data.npy').astype(dtype=np.float32)
  eval_labels = np.load('Eval_labels.npy').astype(dtype=np.int32) 

  # Create the Estimator
  mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
      model_fn=cnn_model_fn)

  # Set up logging for predictions
  # Log the values in the "Softmax" tensor with label "probabilities"
  tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
  logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
      tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

  # Train the model
  train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": train_data},
      y=train_labels,
      batch_size=100,
      num_epochs=None,
      shuffle=True)
  mnist_classifier.train(
      input_fn=train_input_fn,
      steps=5000,
      hooks=[logging_hook])

  # Evaluate the model and print results
  eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": eval_data},
      y=eval_labels,
      num_epochs=1,
      shuffle=False)
  eval_results = mnist_classifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
  print(eval_results)

  # Evaluate single image
  #single_image_predict = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      #x = {"x":


if __name__ == "__main__":
  tf.app.run()
```

Full Error:

```
File "C:/Users/smith25/Documents/Proof of Clean/Dish Machine Camera/Glasses MSE with OneHot.py", line 162, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\smith25\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:/Users/smith25/Documents/Proof of Clean/Dish Machine Camera/Glasses MSE with OneHot.py", line 145, in main
    hooks=[logging_hook])
  File "C:\Users\smith25\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 363, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\smith25\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 843, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\smith25\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 856, in _train_model_default
    features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "C:\Users\smith25\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 831, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/smith25/Documents/Proof of Clean/Dish Machine Camera/Glasses MSE with OneHot.py", line 100, in cnn_model_fn
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=labels, predictions=logits)
  File "C:\Users\smith25\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\losses\losses_impl.py", line 629, in mean_squared_error
    predictions.get_shape().assert_is_compatible_with(labels.get_shape())
  File "C:\Users\smith25\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 844, in assert_is_compatible_with
    raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))
ValueError: Shapes (100, 1) and (100,) are incompatible
```

Comment: On which line do you get your error ?

Comment: I've added in the full error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in

```
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=labels, predictions=logits)
```

`labels` is a Tensor of shape (100,) (i.e. it has only 1 dimension, it's a vector), while `logits` is a Tensor of shape (100, 1) (it's a 2D matrix, for which one dimension happens to be of size 1). See how it used to be of shape  `[batch_size, 5]`, now it's the same with 1 instead of 5). You need the same shape for both arguments of `mean_squared_error`, so you need to do:

```
logits = tf.squeeze(tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=1))  # go from  [batch_size, 1] to [batch_size]
```

Besides, if you're now doing regression instead of classification (i.e. trying to predict a number, not a class), then `logits` contains this number, and `"classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1)` and  `"probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")` don't mean anything anymore, you can drop it: there is only 1 dimension in logits (the batch dimension).

Comment: That seemed to work! Now i'm a little confused about how to do predictions/log outcomes then, as I had to remove the "classes: and "probabilities" as you mentioned for it to run, as well as all logging. Is there a tensor to add back in for logging? I suppose previously it displayed some confidence in each classification option, this doesn't exist anymore (a confidence value) does it? Rather, I just get a scalar output?

Comment: I don't know what you're logging or how your logging works, but you could put `predictions={"value": logits}`, and use it instead of the `classes` you had.